# Filter a part of String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array and its data shows on a table. [Live Code](https://jsfiddle.net/abcid/WWscZ/7/)

Filter by date or by name are working well.

1. I write some more code to show "No Data Found" if users enter a name, which is not on the list, but somehow it doesn't work.
2. Is there any way to write a code which will show a result if users enter only last name or first name, that matches last names or first names on the list?

Please give a hand.  Thanks!

HTML

```
<p>From: <input class="datepicker" id="dateFrom" type="text"> To: <input class="datepicker" id="dateTo" type="text"><button  class="buttApply">APPLY</button></p>
 
    Search by Name<input type="text" id="searchByName"><button type="button"  id="byNamebutton">SEARCH</button><span id="errmsg"></span> 
    
    <div class="text"></div>
    <table id="myTable" border="1" width="300" cellpadding="5">
      
    </table>
```

JS

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();

var dateList =[
  {
        name: "Mike Jenson",
        email: "mike_j@yesware.com",
        phone: "9433550193",
        joined: "05/23/2014",
    },
    {
        name: "Jim Stevens",
        email: "jim_s@yesware.com",
        phone: "1299331944",
        joined: "05/22/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Paul Smith",
        email: "paul_s@yesware.com",
        phone: "4351289654",
        joined: "04/14/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Sarah Andrews",
        email: "sarah_a@yesware.com",
        phone: "1299332944",
        joined: "03/15/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Edward O'Brien",
        email: "edward_ob@yesware.com",
        phone: "4782456897",
        joined: "03/27/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Nicole Plano",
        email: "nicole_p@yesware.com",
        phone: "6657831564",
        joined: "03/30/2013"
    },
    {
        name: "Peter Min",
        email: "peter_m@yesware.com",
        phone: "8893923938",
        joined: "01/07/2013"
    },
    {
        name: "Aaron Jackson",
        email: "aaron_j@yesware.com",
        phone: "6174896315",
        joined: "04/11/2014"
    }
    ];

    $('#byNamebutton').click(
        function()
            {
                var Namefilter = dateList.filter(function(NameItem)
                    {
                      if(NameItem.name == $('#searchByName').val())
                        {
                            return  NameItem.name == $('#searchByName').val();
                        }
                      else
                        {
                            $('#mytable').append('No data found!');
                        }
                     });
                
                refreshTable(Namefilter); 
            }
    );

        $('.buttApply').click(
            function()
            {   
                var filtered = dateList.filter(function(item){
                    return item.joined >= $('#dateFrom').val() && item.joined <= $('#dateTo').val();
                });
                
                refreshTable(filtered);
               
                
            }
        );


    
    function refreshTable(list){
        $("#myTable").html("");
        for (var i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            var tr="<tr>";
            var td1 = "<td>" + list[i]["name"] + "</td>";
            var td2 = "<td>" + list[i]["email"] + "</td>";
            var td3 = "<td>" + list[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
            var td4 = "<td>" + list[i]["joined"] + "</td></tr>";
            $('#myTable').append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4);
        }
    }
    
    refreshTable(dateList);
```

Comment: If this is a learning experience, you're off to a good start.  If you're just trying to get this done, you're re-inventing the wheel.  There are plenty of plugins that do all kinds of filtering.  JQuery DataTables is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your search by name to work by containing phrase and ignore case sensitive:

```
return  NameItem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#searchByName').val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
```

As for the no data found, you just need to include this in the end of your reFreshTable function:

```
    if(list.length==0){
         $('#myTable').html("No Data Found");
    }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/juvian/WWscZ/9/

I would also recommend If your data is not very large to change your `$('#byNamebutton').click(`  for a  `$('#searchByName').keyup(` to make it more responsive, as it filters as you type

Comment: Thank you so much! it works well and yes, I try `keyup`, it is quick response.

Comment: Hi Juvian, one concern about `keyup`: there are more than 2 words users need to type in for searching, but `keyup` is strike at the first word - then users can not search as expected!  Any comment?

Comment: @abcidd you mean 2 characters? To only enable searching if the search has at least 2 characters?

Answer (score 0):

For #1 add at line 91,

```
   if ($('#myTable').html() == "") {
   var tr="<tr>";
            var td1 = "<td colspan=4>No Results Found</td></tr>";
            $('#myTable').append(tr+td1);

        }
```

This addresses your #2 question:

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1:

On line 59, use this instead:

```
                return  NameItem.name.indexOf($('#searchByName').val()) > -1;
```

It will search for partial instead of entire matches. So if you search for "Mike" or "Jensen" it will return "Mike Jensen".